# Protractor does not recognise extends

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, jasmine, protractor

I have basic inheritance:

```
export class Page {}
export class LoginPage extends Page {}
```

In test I have:

```
it('should do sth', ()=> {
    let loginPage = new LoginPage();
```

What I get is:

> Error: ReferenceError: __extends is not defined

Does [protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/) support extends ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Are you using ES6 for your protractor tests? If you are using ES5, probably not (see [ECMAScript 6 equivalents in ES5](https://github.com/addyosmani/es6-equivalents-in-es5#classes)).

There is a discussion on using ES6 with protractor... [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2049).

There will be Typescript support soon and that will allow you to extend a class Page.